# Can the top of the foundation wall be angled to widen basement stairway

Tags: basement, foundation, laundry

The widest part of my basement stairway is 26".  Most full size laundry machines are 27" in some dimension. We would like to upgrade from our economy/compact units to newer and larger machines. Can the foundation wall be ground down on an angle to provide more room to accommodate larger appliances?

[[image: top view 1]]

[[image: top view 2]]

[[image: bottom view 1]]

Comment: If this was my house, I'd get a price for cutting a door into the basement and installing hatch doors on top. Alternately (less preferred but probably cheaper), you could cut a hatch into the floor of a less-used room on the first floor into which you'd lower big appliances.

Comment: Looking at the answers from Jack and Charles I think you should ignore mine!  It's not just the absence of joists there, the wall is also keeping out the garden.  You'll spend a lot of money and have nothing to show for it except a larger washing machine in the basement.  Either buy a 24 inch machine or invest the money in an actual improvement to your home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no engineer, but I do know what the building code requires for foundation walls, and they require particular wall thicknesses for good reason. To "thin" the wall down is not advised. This unless you know what the wall is made of, how it is reinforced if any.

What I do know about code, for a masonry block wall (CMU) concrete masonry unit, is the proper term, that is the grade on the outside of a given wall is up to 5' in height, the wall only needs to be 8" thick. If the grade is over 5' in height, which I am sure yours is, since there is a door to the outside there, the walls are required to be 12" thick. I have seen what happens when this rule is not followed. The pressure from the dirt, ESPECIALLY when waterlogged from long rains or melting snow... as in the case I referred to, the wall will buckle in, and much dirt and/or mud will flow into the basement.

If your wall is made on poured concrete, these requirements are different. If it is poured concrete with rebar in it and depending on how much, it is different still. Thinner walls are allowed.

Now all that being said, you do have, what looks to be a "parged wall"... material added, mortar of one type or another, to the surface of the wall to give it either a better waterproofing advantage or a better esthetic look. That is usually applied approx. 3/4" thick or more, that could be chipped off, but I can't say what it is there for, whether it was for looks or for waterproofing.

Answer (score 1):

From an engineering perspective you may be able to remove a slice of that wall.  The inner portion near the top where it isn't supporting any joists.
It depends on how thick the wall is, and whether the outer portion of the wall, supporting the exterior wall of your house, will remain sound.  You ought to have an architect or engineer look at it.  Some foundation walls are almost two feet thick.  Others are, well, less.

From a practical/financial perspective, to do this without damaging the *entire* top of the wall, including the part supporting the exterior wall, would be difficult. You can't just bash it away.  You would have to hire a concrete sawing company.  Call one, ask them to come look and give you a quote.  It might be cheaper to widen the stair opening from the opposite side, though I realize that would entail moving an interior wall on the first floor and giving up some space in the room adjacent to the stair case.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Concrete is cut and ground with a diamond tools.  Also, a stone mason could work the foundation back by hand,with hammer and chisels.

But I’m not the one that is going to advise you to go for it. After a lot of expense and labor you would still have a narrow stairway. For similar expense and labor, you could make a nice improvement to your home. Like widening the stairway, or putting in an egress window.

We use a 24in wide top-loader wash machine. I don’t believe that it is considered a compact washer. It is labeled “Sears Large Capacity,” “Model 110.” I’ve seen the same, or similar machines sold with different labels.